# Escape comma in batch file to execute a graphicsmagick command

Tags: file, batch-file, cmd, graphicsmagick

I've got the line `gm -mogrify -level 30%,10,100% Edit.jpg` in a .bat file that executes perfectly when I type it manually. However, it ends the line on the first comma of the argument when executed as a batch script.

How should I rewrite this to make it work?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`%` is a special character in batch script. Use `%%` instead.